# How to join two tables in an UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following tables: "users" and "tweets"

```
user_id name             tweet_id user_id tweet        spam
-----------------        ----------------------------------
1       SUSPENDED        1        1       lorem ipsum  0
2       foo              2        1       dolor        0
3       bar              3        2       samet        0
4       SUSPENDED        4        1       stunitas     0
                         5        3       hello        0
                         6        4       spamzz!      0
```

I want to update the "tweets" table by marking all tweets made by SUSPENDED users, as spam. So in the above example, tweets with tweet_id 1, 2, 4 and 6 would be marked as spam by updating the "spam" value from 0 to 1.

I'm having trouble joining the two tables. Until now, I've only had to join in SELECT statements, but this seems more troublesome:

```
UPDATE tweets SET spam = 1 WHERE tweets.user_id = users.user_id 
AND users.name = 'SUSPENDED'
```

This surely isn't working...who could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you need  to specify a `JOIN` between the tables:

```
UPDATE tweets JOIN users ON tweets.user_id = users.user_id
  SET tweets.spam = 1
WHERE users.name = 'SUSPENDED'
```

Comment: Thanks! And if I want to just view all tweets made by suspended accounts? I'm trying SELECT tweets.tweet JOIN users ON tweets.user_id = users.user_id WHERE users.name = 'SUSPENDED' but I get an error? "Check error at JOIN". Doesn't the same convention go for SELECT statements?

Comment: @Reveller you forgot your `FROM`:  `SELECT tweet FROM tweets JOIN users ON tweets.user_id = users.user_id WHERE users.name = 'SUSPENDED'`

Comment: @Michael Berkowski I have tried this type of query. But when records reach 30k Boundary server stopped. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @BhavinChauhan You may not have indexes on the joined columns. Ensure both of them have an index or there is a foreign key relationship.

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski Yes Thanks for comment, I have tried to add Primary key and it works like magic :) tested 5 lakh records.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE tweets
INNER JOIN users ON (users.user_id = tweets.user_id)
SET spam=1
WHERE users.name='SUSPENDED'
```

You can generally use `JOIN` the same in an `UPDATE` as you can in a `SELECT`. You wouldn't be able to join a table to itself in an `UPDATE`, and there are some other little quirks, but for basic stuff like this it'll work as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Started answering before verifying the type of server you are using.  I know this works in MS SQL Server.  I am not sure about MySQL however.  Don't have MySQL installed so give it a try.

```
UPDATE tweets SET
  spam = 1
FROM tweets INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = tweets.user_id
WHERE users.name = 'SUSPENDED'
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose, you have 3 tables and need to update one column from one `table` with another `table`. There are several ways to do this. 
Please look into this `query` for example.

```
update Table1 T1, Table2 T2, Table3 T3 set T1.field_name = T3.field_name where (T1.field_name = T2.field_user_name) and (T2.field_id = T3.entity_id);
```

Relation between `tables` must be maintained carefully.